# Redirect main domain to level 3 subfolder without changing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Let's say my domain is mydomain.com
My structure is root>subfolder1>subfolder2>subfolder3>index.php
How can I redirect domain so that mydomain.com points to subfolder1>subfolder2>subfolder3>index.php without changing url? I have a htaccess in subfolder3 which takes care of parsing url so it has to be unchanged.

.htaccess code in subfolder3:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm making a progress with
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Web/Portal/App/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]

But still cant get css and js to get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess under website root with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, you are on right track. I've updated question, can you take a look again?

Comment: Yes actually If my base url (one that was redirected from) was www.mydomain.com I've had to add as base url www.mydomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3

Comment: Can you explain difference between RewriteRule ^(.*)$ and RewriteRule ^/?$ ?

Comment: Ok, as i'm using part of url for routing after / i've needed ^(.*)$ (so that not only landing page is redirected, that's why it woks now).
Here's working base:
<base href="www.mydomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3">

Now it works like charm!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101208/discussion-between-nenad-milosavljevic-and-anubhava).

Comment: is there any way to skip specific subdomains? like cdn.mydomain.com or admin.mydomain.com?
I'm trying to target subfolder 2 as cdn but I'm getting 500error with this code in .htaccess.
cdn.mydomain.com is pointed to subfolder2.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes add this condition before this rule: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(cdn|admin)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried to filter it in RewriteRule directly.